# Java Application Window Symbols don't show up

Tags: java

I am building a simple calculator in java Application window, everything works fine, however when i want to add an backspace symbol to the calculator it doesn't show up.
In the code i have:[image]

In the application window i changed the font to Wingdings, however the symbol does not appear on the calculator screen i just have a regular button which has a strange square symbol in it.
[image]

Comment: Does it show up when _running_ the application? Maybe the preview isn't simply working

Comment: Wingdings has `\u00d5` (rub-out) or `\u00df` (left arrow). Simple evade Wingdings.

Comment: Which character are you trying to display?  Note that [Wingdings only has characters for codepoints 32–255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings#Character_set).

Comment: i am trying to display Backspace character <--- this one, however it doesn't work, even when i run the app.

Comment: Remove your call to `setFont` and it will work.  Java will assemble the fonts on your system to create virtual fonts that support as much of Unicode as possible, and one of those virtual fonts is the default font for Swing components.

Comment: Okay it worked when i removed setFont, however what if i want to change the size of that symbol, when i do it it automatically setsfont and the symbol dissapears, what should i do if i want to change size of that symbol then?

Comment: To change the size, get the button’s current Font, and call [deriveFont(float)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) to get a Font with the same family.  **CAUTION:** Make sure you pass a `float` and not an int—passing an int will call a different deriveFont method that will change the style instead of the size!

Comment: btnX.getFont().deriveFont((float) 20); wrote like the, however it didn't work older size was 11 i wrote 20 however it didn't change the size :((. I think it is because, i don't have any font, since i deleted it (i deleted setfont as u said)